# Need help in getting amp form to work

Tags: amp-html

I'm working on getting an amp-form setup for a client, I've got the form styled here:

```
<form name="AMPform"
method="post"
action-xhr="blank"
target="_top">
<div><label for="name"></p> <h4>Name:</h4> <p></label><br />     <input type="text"       name="firstname"       placeholder="First"       required>
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last" required><br /></p>
<h4>Address:</h4> 
<p><input type="text" name="streetaddress" placeholder="Street Address" required></p>
<p><input type="text" name="addressline2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required>
<input type="text" name="stateprovinceregion" placeholder="State/Province/Region" required></p>
<p><input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="ZIP / Postal Code" required>
<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" required><br /></p> 
<h4>Contact Information:</h4>
<p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required></p>
<p><input type="tel"  name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone..."><br /></div>
<div><br /><label for="help">What can we help you with?</label><br /><br />
<select name="help" id="help"><option value="neuro">Brain Training/Neurofeedback</option><option value="concussion">Concussion/Brain Injury/Brain Trauma</option><option value="add">ADD/ADHD/Autism/MS/PD/Stroke</option><option value="forensic">Forensic Consultant and Expert Testimony</option><option value="sports">Sports/Performing Arts Psychology</option><option value="education">Education/Training</option><option value="other">Other</option></select></p>
<p><label for="hear about us">How did you hear about us?</label><br /><br />
<select name="hear-about-us" id="hear about us"><option value="referral">Referral (Clinician/Professional)</option><option value="psychologytoday">Psychology Today Blog</option><option value="internet">Internet/Website</option><option value="books">Book(s)</option><option value="workshop">Workshop/Speech</option><option value="newsletter">Newsletter</option><option value="other">Other</option></select></p>
<p><textarea name="message" placeholder="Comments/Questions" required></textarea></div>
<p></p><div><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></div><br />
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<br /> 
<div submit-success><template type="amp-mustache"><br />Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.<br /></template></div>
<div submit-error><template type="amp-mustache"><br />Something went wrong, please try again later.<br /></template></div></p></form><br />
```

I need to figure out how to make an action-xhr so that on pressing the submit button, all of the form information will be emailed to my client, but I am unsure how to set that up properly.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

So here's what you need to do:

1. Include the amp-form script
2. Set action-xhr attribute to your backend url
3. Your back-end should return a JSON response with `Content-Type: application/json`
4. Backend should return a 200 status code for success and a 400 for errors.
5. Your returned JSON object will render in either  submit-success or submit-error containers respectively.

It's really very simple.